# Modify result of .serialize() on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I want to get form fields but in the meantime I want to change some field's data before sending the request to the server and other fields should not be changed.

I have this jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'Post',
  url: '/Employee/EducationCreate',
  data: $("#form").serialize(),
  success: function () {
    var url = '/Employee/Education?EmployeeId=' + $("#employeeId").val();                          
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    errorHandler(xhr);
  }
});
```

if I use:

```
var forms = $("#form").serialize(); 
                forms += "&StartDate=" + encodeURIComponent(georgianStartDate);
```

Then I will have an array of StartDate in output, but all I want is modify `$("#form").serialize()` not appending or adding an extra parameter.

Comment: create your own data object and store field in that.

Comment: If you have fewer fields to update, then is this okay? 

var new_val='abc';
var old_val=$('[name="my_field_val"]').val();
$('[name="my_field_val"]').val(new_val);
var data=$("#form").serialize();
$('[name="my_field_val"]').val(old_val);
console.log(data);

Comment: the form is dynamic so no, I have not few fields.

Comment: Okay, I mean update the value just before serializing and revert back after serializing.

Comment: it's a hard way